# a regular expression for whose name has a minimum of 3 digits,2 special chars & starts with a character and ends with a digit

Tags: java

I tried to solve it but am not getting the output

and I have used this expression

```
"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{1,})?(?=.*[0-9A-Za-z@#$%^&+=()])"+"(?=.*[a-zA-Z[0-9]{3,}[@#$%^&+=()]{2,}])"
            +"(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])"+"(\\d)$" ;
```

can anyone help me in this regard

Comment: Do you know https://regexr.com/?

Comment: Regular expressions are seriously the wrong tool for this.  Just loop through the password and count the characters.  Check the first and last character explicitly with Character.isDigit and Character.isLetter.